# how to get download urls of multiple image uploads to firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am uploading two "user-selected" images to firebase storage and getting their URL to save to the firestore, but the URLs save point to only one of the pictures although they don't appear to be the same. 
there is a similar question but about swift and it doesn't answer my question, here is the URL to that.
[get download url from multiple file upload firebase storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318776/get-download-url-from-multiple-file-upload-firebase-storage)

I tried getting the download links with ref.getDownloadUrl() but that gave wrong URLs and tasksnapshot.getDownloadUrl() doesn't work anymore. 
I tried reading lots of answers but nothing helped most are outdated with tasksnapshot.getDownloadUrl() method.

```
        if (profileImageUri != null) {

            //upload first image
            profileImageRef.putFile(profileImageUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        profileImageUrl = String.valueOf(downloadUri);
                        saveUserInfo(); // method to save the URLs along with other info
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "upload failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    btSaveInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }

        if (coverImageUri != null) {

            // Upload second image
            profileImageRef.putFile(coverImageUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downloadCUri = task.getResult();
                        coverImageUrl = String.valueOf(downloadCUri);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cover Picture Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "Cover picture upload failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } 
                }
            });
```

the two images are uploaded I can see them in my firebase console but the URLs saved in firestore both load the same image although they are not the same,  they look like this,

1. https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sefnetapp-39b37.appspot.com/o/profilePics%2F1561103180500.jpg?alt=media&token=8dd5ee93-9bbc-46ee-89b9-fb5ae5b36128
2. https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sefnetapp-39b37.appspot.com/o/profilePics%2F1561103180500.jpg?alt=media&token=c153c59b-c6b3-428b-a845-3db3b19a38e3

how do I get the two URLs that will load the two pictures that I uploaded not only one

thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: I deleted the collection from my database and added new entries from start and now it works fine for me some users but for others the cover URL is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I wasn't saving my info after uploading the cover image, I added the saveInfo method in my onComplete of cover image upload method also and it works fine now.

```
    final StorageReference profileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                .getReference(SefnetContract.PROFILE_PICS_REF + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        // Upload profile picture
        if (profileImageUri != null) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            profileImageRef.putFile(profileImageUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        profileImageUrl = String.valueOf(downloadUri);
                        saveUserInfo();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "upload failed: "
                                + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
        if (coverImageUri != null) {
            // Upload cover picture
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            profileImageRef.putFile(coverImageUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downloadCUri = task.getResult();
                        coverImageUrl = String.valueOf(downloadCUri);
                        saveUserInfo();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cover Picture Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "Cover picture upload failed: "
                                + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I still feel like it could be done in a better way so if you know of a method better than this please share. I would like a method in which I can stop the user from initializing the upload method too many times by clicking the button repeatedly, thank you

Comment: i separated the methods for two image uploads and saved images in different references e.g. cover/ and profile/ and it worked